# Load html on a browser from a different computer on a network

Tags: php, html

I have a bit of problem. I have created an HTML file on my desktop. I want to access this html file on a browser from my laptop which is connected on the same network with my desktop. How can I get it to work?
I am using WAMP on my desktop. What I want to happen is that, when any devices connected to my network (tables, phones, laptops) typed in their browser "orders/" the orders.html file from my desktop will be loaded.

Comment: It's more convenient that the remote computer has web server & host the file with it. Else, double click on the remote HTML file can still be able to launch the file in browser.

Comment: Setup some webserver like Wamp and then you can access it from another computer by entering url http://LAN_IP/. or even from outside of lan by entering WAN IP

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a server on the machine hosting the file. If the machine is a Mac its very easy, there's a built-in web server. For Windows its a bit tougher, but you still need a server.

Fortunately its really easy these days. There's a simple tool called Forward you can install in a minute and it'll run a server. https://forwardhq.com/#

Comment: So, you still need a server. Its all the same technology, whether local or on the internet. Do the simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the address to open your html file in your desktop is
http://localhost/orders/orders.html
on your laptop you need to open
http://your-desktop-ip/orders/orders.html,
eg.- http://192.168.0.2/orders/orders.html

Comment: This answer is not wrong. However, the OP probably has a WAMP stack which is configured to listen only on `localhost (127.0.0.1)`, or he might have problems with his desktop's firewall.

Comment: Don't know about WAMP much, I use XAMPP which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [virtual host in wamp](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=how%20to%20create%20wamp%20virtual%20host) which points to the parent folder of that html file.
2. Give a fake domain that vhost like `files.mydomain.local`
3. Now you need to tell other devices on network about this "hey, there is a local domain named files.mydomain.local which points to my ip address 192.168.X.X". There are two options to do this:

**Option A :**

Put this information by adding a new line to each device's hosts file (For windows: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` For macs: `/etc/hosts` )

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
::1          localhost
192.168.X.X  files.mydomain.local # Change 192.168.X.X with your local ip
```

**Option B :**

Roll your very own DNS server. (This will not be easy if you don't have enough knowledge about DNS and network systems)

Comment: what if I will be using a table pc for loading the html file from my desktop?